# Connect to SQL Server 2008 R2 database from Windows forms application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm new to .Net Framework. I need to have a database connected with my Windows Form application. I created a database in SQL Server Management Studio and the application is created with VS 2010 (C#).

I wasn't able to find a way to connect my database from the application (need to have the connection when form loading). Please guide me on the way. Are there any related stuffs to mysql jdbc connector?

Thanks in advance
Madhura

Comment: You should try something and If you're facing any error, we can help you. Go Google for some starting lessons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to the database using the `SqlConnection` class and perform actions.

You need to pass a connection string, http://www.connectionstrings.com/ gives you complete list of connection strings for various datasources

Well it requires you to read a lot more than that! connection will only establish connection but do not perform any operations. So google and read on `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataAdapter`, LINQ, ADO, `SqlParameter` etc.

Answer (score 4):

Put Connection string in app.config as

```
<configuration>
    <configsections>
    </configsections>
    <connectionstrings>
        <add name="connection string">
            connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\App_Data\HREChk.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </add></connectionstrings>
</configuration>
```

**THEN** You can make simple connection,execute select query and read data from reader as:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("connection string")) 
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) 
{ 
    conn.Open(); 
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id FROM foo;"; 
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
    { 
        while (reader.Read()) 
        { 
            // ... 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi Following is the code for Db connection

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet() ;

        SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=UrDB;Initial Catalog=es_NG;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=;Connection Timeout=600");
       // SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;User ID=;Password=;Connection Timeout=600");
        Con.Open();
        string SqlQry = "select top 100 first_name,last_name,email_address  from user";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlQry, Con); 
        DataTable dtTbl = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dtTbl);
```

Thanks
Uttam